# JMenuBar doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar, null-layout-manager

I am trying to create a Menubar, but for some reason it doesn't show up. Google research did not help. I put `setVisible(true)` at the end, I added the Menubar to the window and I added Menupoints into the bar as well. However it still doesn't show up.

```
public MusicPlayerGUI(){
        setLayout(null);
        
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
        setTitle("MusicPlayer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,700);
        
        initComponent();
        add(bar);
        add(edit);
        add(show);
        add(createPlaylist);
        add(addSong);
        add(all);
        add(genre);
        add(rock);
        add(indie);
        add(playlists);
    
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void initComponent() {
        //Menubar
        bar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(bar);
        edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        bar.add(edit);
        show = new JMenu("Show");
        bar.add(show);
        createPlaylist = new JMenuItem("Create new Playlist");
        edit.add(createPlaylist);
        addSong = new JMenuItem("Add new Song");
        edit.add(addSong);
        all = new JMenuItem("All");
        show.add(all);
        genre = new JMenuItem("Genre");
        show.add(genre);
        rock = new JMenuItem("Rock");
        genre.add(rock);
        indie = new JMenuItem("Indie");
        genre.add(indie);
        playlists = new JMenuItem("Playlists");
        show.add(playlists);
        
        
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) Fix (2), and if problem persists, post (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In initComponent() you use:

```
setJMenuBar(bar);
```

which is correct.

But then in your constructor you attempt to add the "bar" to the frame again:

```
    initComponent();
    add(bar); // delete this line
```

Which removes the menubar from the reseverd area of the frame. And because you are using a null layout and the "bar" has a size of (0, 0) by default there is nothing to paint.

1. a component can only have a single parent, don't attempt to add the component twice.
2. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.